# Not able to create responsive layout in android

Tags: android, layout, responsive

I am creating a layout in android but I am not able to create a responsive layout. I have defined font size in pt but it distort on small screen. What should I do to make it responsive for all device. I have worst problem of font size. Screenshot on small screen is:

[image]

// My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background_car_detail"
android:elevation="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".8"
android:background="@drawable/car">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtCertified"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top|left"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
android:alpha="0.5"
android:background="@drawable/btn_right_curve"
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:text="Certified"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/status"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:text="Sold"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_weight="1.2"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Mahindra TUV300 T6 Plus"
android:textSize="14sp" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carKm"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="29,6789 Km"
android:textSize="5pt" />

<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"
android:layout_marginRight="2pt"
android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carType"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Disel"
android:textSize="5pt" />

<View
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"
android:layout_marginRight="2pt"
android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carYear"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="2016"
android:textSize="5pt" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carCondition"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:text="Condition: Excellent"
android:textSize="5pt" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carAmount"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp"
android:text="Rs. 7.5L"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/carAddress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:text="Singh car, Rajori Garden, Delhi"
android:textSize="5pt" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to layout your weights

Comment: Implement weights and scrollView if needed

Comment: make your parent layout  height match parent and use weight

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya  how can I make my image responsive for all devices. In this I have hardcoded height

Comment: have you check? @dheerajsingh

Comment: what ? @Hasmukhkachhatiya . Yes, I did

Comment: add your frame to linearlayout and set weight to that layout as 1

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

[image: Created this]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_button_like_background">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCertified"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_button_background"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Certified"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_button_background"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:text="Sold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mahindra TUV300 T6 Plus"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carKm"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="29,6789 Km"
                    android:textSize="5pt" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2pt"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Disel"
                    android:textSize="5pt" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2pt"
                    android:background="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carYear"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2016"
                    android:textSize="5pt" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carCondition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Condition: Excellent"
                android:textSize="5pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Rs. 7.5L"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Singh car, Rajori Garden, Delhi"
                android:textSize="5pt" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```